# Can Young's slit be repeated in the temporal dimension with fast-oscillating lcd's?

Tags: visible-light, spacetime, speed-of-light, laser, interference

Can Young's slit be repeated in the temporal dimension with fast-oscillating lcd's?

Young's slit demonstrates the wave-like properties of light by causing interference from two slits.  Fringes caused by positive and negative interference diverge **in a space dimension**, the further the light travels from the slits.

If instead of separating the slits by space, we separate them by time, can we create interference fringes in the time dimension?

It took me a little time to devise this experiment but I think the method would be to shine a laser through a fast-oscillating lcd which alternates between opaque and translucent.  Then, some distance away we should be able to measure the scintillation of the laser.

If interference patterns can indeed be created in the temporal dimension, we will see that the wavelength of scintillation will increase, the further we move from the laser.

With a very fast lcd this experiment could be realised with a laser beam of less than a mile.

Does this idea stack up?

I think this is a very profound and important experiment because if the result is positive, it implies that the state of the lcd at any **moment** in time, has consequences for the resulting beam, which are **spread out in time** and also **changing in time**, with respect to procession from the lcd.  Therefore some of the consequences have traveled either faster or slower than the speed of light.

Comment: and the extension of the question is... is there anybody on here willing to help me realise this experiment?

Comment: Can you, please, clarify what you mean by scintillation? The way how you use this term indicates that you treat it differently from what I find conventionally accepted.

Comment: @Ilya I mean fluctuations with respect to time, as measured at some distance from the source, in some measurable property of the beam - most probably amplitude.

Comment: LCD displays do not oscillate 'fast', certainly not on timescales of relevance to light. One could perhaps use non-linear crystals to make transient Bragg reflectors or something like that, but the experiment behaves pretty much as one would expect, and certainly not in a 'profound' way.

Comment: @JonCuster There is a form of lcd that oscillates fast enough to carry out the experiment with about a 1 mile laser by my calculation. http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2013/sep/20/lcds-enter-the-fast-lane . As far as I can see scintillation is usually regarded as an unwanted, relatively "random" artefact which is to be eliminated and ignored if it can't be eliminated. I'm not certain this has been studied properly.

Comment: What is a '1 mile laser' - do you mean a coherence length of one mile?

Comment: If you mean just the variation of the amplitude - this is done on a daily basis in optical telecom (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber-optic_communication). There you have laser diodes coupled to the fiber, which are modulated actually much faster (up to couple GHz switch rates) and sent over thousands of kilometers. If there was anything interesting this should have been certainly noticed ages ago.

Comment: @JonCuster no, I mean the measurement would have to be taken 1 mile from the lcd.

Comment: @RobertFrost - while you seem to have a clear idea of the experiment you are proposing, so far it does not seem to be coming across clearly to others. One can very rapidly switch or modulate laser beams, and one doesn't have to be a mile away to take measurements. Perhaps you should sketch out the experiment and what you expect to happen.

Comment: @Ilya maybe you're right an Electro-absorption modulator would be suitable. But you're saying this effect would have been seen in fibre-optics. I think it would need to be an external modulator rather than a directly modulated laser. And care would need to be taken to preserve coherence, in order to deduce a negative result.

Comment: @JonCuster In Young's slit experiment, you have to be some distance away to observe the interference pattern (say $5m$) to get 5mm interference bands from $1mm$ slits (not calculated). In the temporal version, $1mm$ is equivalent to 10 terahertz modulation.  Since we can't approach that frequency we would have to extend the distance from the modulator to the observer by a factor of about a thousand to get the same size interference pattern.  But even with such a long experiment $5mm$ interference bands in the temporal dimension would be about 100 picoseconds apart. Difficult to observe I guess

Comment: @JonCuster perhaps the above ^^ accounts for our failure to observe this effect.

Answer (score 1):

Just examining this set up classically initially, a slit opens at regular intervals modulating a light beam of discrete frequency. Now you don't have two slits, you have a number of slits spaced in time. When it s observed what does the spectrum look like, are there frequencies in it other than that of the original light.

Well, yes, there would be under electromagnetic theory as the absence of e-field at some times in the signal would alter the apparent frequency. A fourier transform/spectral analysis of the signal would reveal the presence of beat frequencies. These are related to the difference between the modulating frequency and the light frequency.

Now you say you are thinking about young's slit experiment, so probably want to consider quantum effects in this scenario. Indeed just as the em wave was modulated by the appearing/disappearing slit, so would a corresponding wave function. If we are releasing individual photons I imagine quantum tunnelling through the closed slit (usually treated as space-tunnelling, tbh), could be significant, and this could impact the modulation frequency and thus the resultant spectra in some specially designed scenarios.

"therefore I've beaten Einstein"
Well, (surprise of surprises), no. A frequency alteration is nothing to do with a change in velocity for light waves, only a change in energy. Thus I don't see a possibility of applying the limitation of the speed of light in this experiment.

Comment: If we knew the result of every experiment in advance, there would be no need for experimentation! But thanks. A positive result implying information within the beam traveling faster or slower than light, doesn't necessarily contradict relativity. But it would nevertheless be interesting.

Comment: "Doesn't necessarily"?? If information is transmitted from a source to a destination faster than c, you have broken/beaten relativity. Check it up by all means. (There are a few interesting scenarios. This doesn't seem like one, unless you have a mechanism in mind I haven't seen).

Comment: E.g. a shadow can travel faster than light, and can contain info. http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SpeedOfLight/FTL.html

Comment: the information doesn't travel with the shadow, it travels from the object to the shadow. Look up "Lighthouse Paradox", "Group Velocity" also may be of interest.

Comment: Yeah, he kind of says no travelling faster than light in a vacuum.