Does the speed limit $c$ survive last year's experiment showing temporal Young's slit interference?
Last year an experiment I designed and proposed just under a decade ago, was finally realised - Young's Slit in the temporal dimension.  Sadly, working outside of science, I lacked the time and resources to conduct the experiment myself, but it is wonderful to see that Professor Ricardo Sappienza and his team have not only made it happen, but also that they concluded I was right - light interferes with itself in the time dimension.
The amazing question that follows on from this experiment is:
Question

Have we finally succeeded in transmitting information faster than the speed of light? Does the speed limit survive the experiment's positive result?

In the original form of the Young's Slit experiment, interference fringes appear both to the left and to the right of the slits.  There is a clear implication, therefore, that in the temporal version, scintillation within the output signal at its destination $l$ metres from the source, with the source signal switching at time $t$, is likely to occur both after, and crucially, before, $t+lc^{-1}$.
This implies information may finally have been transmitted faster than the speed of light.  A good experimental design would be to simply transmit the light over a greater distance in order to yield an arrival a measurable time in advance of the switching.

same question different wording:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/322403/

This question is similar to: Can Young's slit be repeated in the temporal dimension with fast-oscillating lcd's?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@trula no. When I asked that I was asking if the experiment I designed was feasible. A decade on, my exeperiment has been now carried out and the result came up positive.  Now I am asking about its implications for the light speed limit. This is all already clear in the question. It was I who linked the question from a decade ago, which you suggest is a duplicate but I think you haven't read them thoroughly.

The video you linked to explains this. The interference is in the frequency domain. It doesn't show up as dots on a screen, it shows up as changes in color as detected by a frequency analyzer.

I guess the paper is "Double-slit time diffraction at optical frequencies", Nature Physics 19, 999–1002 (2023) (DOI, arXiv). Better to link that than a YouTube video.

When you write that you "designed and proposed" this experiment, do you mean that you were part of the team that authored the Nature Physics article linked in an earlier comment? Or that you had some communication with this team, like a citation from them to some article by you? Or do you mean that you wrote your idea down here on Physics.SE, and now results from a similar experiment have been published?

@rob Not that it's material to the question, but I have no known comms to the team who carried out the experiment. The only way they would have derived their experiment from my proposition is if they read it here or the idea had made the way to them from here in the intervening years, or if either a couple of my friends or Ben Krasnow who I asked to help me realise the experiment in 2015 had conveyed the idea to others, or similarly Oleg Lawrentovich who I discussed it with in 2017 after he invented switching LCD's which would have been among the first fast enough to do so.

Quantum Mechanics is generally considered as "nonlocal" (certainly as to context). It is also considered generally as NOT supporting any kind of signaling in excess of c.  Note that the context can not only be considered as violating causality in space, but also in time.  So it is actually a spatiotemporal violation. In that respect, this experiment follows normal garden variety QM. Note that any of the hundreds of delayed choice experiments that have been performed show the same thing. Some interpretations of QM do not agree. However, the 2022 Nobel was awarded for such experiments.

@DrChinese I can perceive there's some deep insight in your comment but I can't quite put my finger on what it is with total clarity. I suspect you might essentially be saying; faster than $c$ implies time travel/nonparallel causation and on those grounds the idea this experiment breaks $c$ can be ruled impossible.  Is that your point? If so, a great many paradigms were destroyed by eperiment in the past. FWIW I am not as secure as you in my belief that that time travel is entirely impossible (albeit in limited form) although I would sincerely hope that it is impossible.

Thanks for clarifying your possible relation to the published result.  Apart from our usual guidance about clearly identifying self-links and self-citations, your level of connection to the project helps to clarify the appropriate level of technical knowledge for folks to assume when writing an answer to your question.

@rob yeah, I guess that makes sense. FWIW I have reached out to them and proposed they carry out the logical next steps which I intended in the first place - 1. extend the time the light is permitted to travel from the temporal slits and prove fringes get further apart (in time). 2. once the fringes are sufficiently spaced, synchronise with a non-scintillated signal and seek to measure faster than $c$ transmission of information, and 3. Send individual photons and determine whether light is also quantized in the time dimension.
